# Why don't column filters work in DT::datatable when column data has no variability

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

I have a dataframe with a bunch of columns and the last two columns are similar in that they both have one response option for all the rows by default. I'd like to create a *datatable* where I can filter each column. Unfortunately, I can't filter the last two variables. I want to be able to filter all columns because my *datatable* is part of a Shiny project where the *datatable* is editable, so while the last two columns are homogeneous by default, this isn't always the case.

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

iris1 <- iris %>%
    mutate(new = as.character(NA),
           new2 = factor("Open", levels = c("Open", "Closed")))

datatable(iris1, filter = 'top')
```

Comment: Don't the columns become filterable if data is added that makes them have more than one value?

Comment: Great question. Normally, I believe the answer to this would be yes, however I use DT::dataTableProxy to not rerender the whole table upon edits.

Comment: That's interesting! And yeah, I tested without using a proxy, and the re-render causes the filter controls to also reflect the changed contents. I don't think there is a way to update them via a proxy -- at least I can't find one. Maybe that would be a feature request for `DT`?

Comment: Thanks, Mikko! It looks like this issue has been partially resolved -- https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/934 (using DT::updateFIlters()). My issue also has a column with characters.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! The next release should include some enhancements that will hopefully help with your use-case, too.